# Gradient of L 2,1 norm w.r.t a matrix

Tags: optimization

I have previously asked this question but did not get a response. Maybe it was because tag was wrong. I deleted the previous one and asking this again. I have this cost function:
$$f(X)=||AX||_{2,1}$$
I want to derive 
$$\nabla_X f(X)$$
I have done this derivation:
$$[AX]_{ij}=\sum_{k}A_{ik}X_{kj}$$
$$||AX||_{2,1}=\sum_{i}(\sum_{j}(\sum_{k}A_{ik}X_{kj})^2)^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}||AX||_{2,1}=\sum_{i}(\frac{1}{(\sum_{m}(\sum_{l}A_{il}X_{lm})^2)^{1/2}})\sum_{j}(\sum_{k}A_{ik}X_{kj})\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}\sum_{k}A_{ik}X_{kj}$$
$$[\nabla_{X}||AX||_{2,1}]_{ij}=\frac{(\sum_kA_{i,k}X_{kj})A_{ii}}{(\sum_m(\sum_lA_{il}X_{lm})^2)^{1/2}}$$

Does it seem ok to you? Have a nice day.